# MySQL report -- fill in empty dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I am building a query to return daily sales data. My current query returns a table similar to this:

```
----------------------------------
| DATE       | SKU      | TOTAL  | 
----------------------------------
| 2014-11-01 | AV155_A  | 209.00 |
| 2014-11-02 | AV155_B  | 627.00 |
| 2014-11-04 | AV155_C  | 279.00 |
| 2014-11-05 | AV155    | 279.00 |
| 2014-11-08 | AV1556_A | 209.00 |
| 2014-11-09 | AV1556_B | 627.00 |
| 2014-11-10 | AV1556_C | 279.00 |
| 2014-11-12 | AV1556   | 279.00 |
```

What I would like is a results table that displays every day, even if there are no data points for that particular day. Something like this:

```
----------------------------------
| DATE       | SKU      | TOTAL  | 
----------------------------------
| 2014-11-01 | AV155_A  | 209.00 |
| 2014-11-02 | AV155_B  | 627.00 |
| 2014-11-03 |          |      0 |
| 2014-11-04 | AV155_C  | 279.00 |
| 2014-11-05 | AV155    | 279.00 |
| 2014-11-06 |          |      0 |
| 2014-11-07 |          |      0 |
| 2014-11-08 | AV1556_A | 209.00 |
| 2014-11-09 | AV1556_B | 627.00 |
| 2014-11-10 | AV1556_C | 279.00 |
| 2014-11-11 |          |      0 |
| 2014-11-12 | AV1556   | 279.00 |
```

The query I currently have looks like this:

```
select
  DATE_FORMAT(created_on, '%m-%d-%Y') as date,
  sku,
  SUM(price) as total 
FROM order_items
WHERE created_on between FROM_UNIXTIME(1415577600) AND NOW()
GROUP BY MONTH(created_on), DAY(v.created_on), order_item_sku;
```

Comment: I believe that to do this you will either need to execute an UPDATE to insert rows for the dates in a desired range that have no data, or else use SQL's flow control and programming, i.e. create a stored procedure that loops through a date range. Don't see how to do it in a simple SELECT query...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an outer join.  The easiest way is if you have a calendar table, but you can make one on the fly:

```
select c.thedate, oi.sku, sum(price) as total
from (select date('2014-11-01') as thedate union all
             date('2014-11-02') as thedate union all
             date('2014-11-03') as thedate union all
             date('2014-11-04') as thedate union all
             date('2014-11-05') as thedate union all
             date('2014-11-06') as thedate union all
             date('2014-11-07') as thedate union all
             date('2014-11-08') as thedate union all
             date('2014-11-09') as thedate union all
             date('2014-11-10') as thedate union all
             date('2014-11-11') as thedate union all
             date('2014-11-12') as thedate
      ) c left join
      order_items oi
      on c.thedate = date(oi.created_on)
where oi.created_on between FROM_UNIXTIME(1415577600) AND NOW()
group by ci.thedate, oi.sku
```

Comment: Hmm. Yeah, I'll be using this query in my API, so I'll need to be able to dynamically generate the query. How would I go about using a calendar table? I also saw something about using another table's ids to dynamically generate a range of dates..

Comment: @JoelBrewer . . . If you are doing this through an API, can't you just add the additional rows in the application layer?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer that addresses the need for a flexible list of dates. You need to figure out a way to get a virtual table containing all the dates in the appropriate range, and then join them to the summary. Here’s a query that will get the dates in the range.

```
SELECT mintime + INTERVAL seq.seq DAY AS reportdate
  FROM (
        SELECT MIN(DATE(created_on)) AS mintime,
               MAX(DATE(created_on)) AS maxtime
          FROM order_items
         WHERE created_on >= starting_time
           AND created_on <= NOW()
       ) AS order_items
  JOIN seq_0_to_999 AS seq 
                    ON seq.seq < TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,mintime,maxtime)
```

What’s going on here? Three things.

1. We have a subquery which determines the first and last day (min and max created_on) we care about reporting.
2. We apply a time range to that query. I like to avoid using `BETWEEN` for timestamp ranges because it often gets the ending time wrong in an off-by-one-second error.
3. We have a table called seq_0_to_999. It contains a sequence of a thousand cardinal numbers: the integers starting at zero. More about this in a moment.

Then, you can join that as a subquery to your aggregate query to get all the dates in the range listed, like so.

```
select  DATE_FORMAT(d.reportdate, '%m-%d-%Y') as date,
        sku,
        SUM(price) as total 
   FROM (
          SELECT mintime + INTERVAL seq.seq DAY AS reportdate
            FROM (
                  SELECT MIN(DATE(created_on)) AS mintime,
                         MAX(DATE(created_on)) AS maxtime
                    FROM order_items
                   WHERE created_on >= starting_time
                     AND created_on <= NOW()
                 ) AS order_items
            JOIN seq_0_to_999 AS seq 
                              ON seq.seq < TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,mintime,maxtime)
        ) AS d
   LEFT JOIN order_items ON d.reportdate = DATE(order_items.created_on)       
   WHERE created_on >= starting_time
     AND created_on <= NOW()
   GROUP BY d.reportdate, sku
   ORDER BY d.reportdate, sku
```

It looks like a big nasty hairball of a query.  But if you think of it as a sandwich made of various layers of queries, it really isn't that complicated.

It uses `LEFT JOIN` so it makes sure all the dates in the range are preserved even if there's no corresponding data in your `order_items` table.

Finally, what about this `seq_0_to_999` table? Where do we get those integers starting with zero?  The answer is this: we have to arrange to do that; those numbers aren’t built in to MySQL. (They are built into the MySQL fork called MariaDB.) Create a short table with the integers from 0-9 in it, like so:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS seq_0_to_9;
CREATE TABLE seq_0_to_9 AS
   SELECT 0 AS seq UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9;
```

Then create a view that joins that table with itself to generate 1000 combinations like this:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS seq_0_to_999;
CREATE VIEW seq_0_to_999 AS (
SELECT (a.seq + 10 * (b.seq + 10 * c.seq)) AS seq
  FROM seq_0_to_9 a
  JOIN seq_0_to_9 b
  JOIN seq_0_to_9 c
);
```

I wrote this up in some detail at http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/filling-missing-data-sequences-cardinal-integers/

Comment: Hmm. This looks really good, and I think I'm really close, but for some reason it still isn't filling in the missing dates..

Comment: I have the same issue - the gaps are still there but the query now is incredibly slow